# GAE AppStats shows no GQL queries

Tags: python, google-app-engine, appstats

I run default AppStats at my local GAE/Python server. Details for both `datastore_v3.RunQuery` and `datastore_v3.Get` are shown by AppStats with no useful information about GQL queries (below).

Is there a way to view actual queries still?

UPD. I don't use GQL queries directly but indirectly via get() and fetch(). I'm talking about how to view what took these 500 ms. Current info is useless and a user should investigate stack trace for that.

```
Request: Query<app_='dev~app', compile_=True, composite_index_=[], filter_=[Query_Filter<...>], ...>
Request: Query<app_='dev~app', compile_=True, composite_index_=[], filter_=[Query_Filter<...>], ...>
Request: GetRequest<key_=[Reference<app_='dev~app', has_app_=1, has_path_=1, path_=Path<...>>, ...], ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

GQL is just a layer on top of the datastore; a GQL query is executed the same way as a db.Query, and results in the same RPC.

Comment: Actually I didn't use queries like SELECT directly but `db.get()` and `Entity.all().fetch()`. I just meant it would be quite worth to view what the query took 500 ms.

Comment: In that case, I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Well. I do `Article.get_them()`. Then I open AppStats. I expand a RPC-call information. I see useless information like `Query<app_='dev~app', compile_=True` there. Instead I want to see appropriate GQL query (word "Article" at least, to be able to distinguish queries one from another). Is it possible?

Comment: @PavelVlasov The kind being queried is definitely in the trace somewhere. Have you tried expanding all the relevant sections?

Comment: It is pretty hard to view the source to understand what was the query. The same time GAE Mini Profiler does shows some useful info on that. It just strange a bit AppStats does not. Well, gonna revert to GMP.